# Arduino program code in .data

Tags: arduino

It seems as though some of my functions are being placed into the .data section.  This is for a library that has classes.

I've looked at the memory map as suggested here: 
[http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group_*demo*_project.html](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__demo__project.html)

I've also been using avr-size to see the size of the .data and .text questions.

Any ideas why the program code is getting placed in .data and not .text?

Comment: Add a section of the code and the map that shows the example of what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out what was happening.

It only looked like code was going into the .data section.  What was actually going in there were the char * from debug messages and thus taking up large fractions of space.

For example, I had a bunch of `Serial.println("debug message that is a long string.");`  An easy way around this for Serial.println is the use of the F() macro, which stores the string in FLASH instead of RAM (.data section I was seeing).

Also, this link provides some good info on memory conservation of strings:
http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM